# If the page doesn't require Javascript, what could be blocking it?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

For example, this URL: http://websta.me/n/victoria.a3456

In a request, everything loads but the photos and everything within those divs like their comments, etc. But the footer and the header (down to the photos) loads like their bio, profile pic, etc.

So in the browser, I've disabled javascript and set the user-agent to `python-requests/1.2.0`. The page still loads fine in the browser.

I don't understand why it won't load by a programatic HTTP request.

Comment: Check `Referrer` and `Accept` headers, also compression settings (if that would be the case, you might see some errors).

Comment: @jso is there a way to set my chrome headers to the same of `wget` or `requests` so I can see if that's my problem?

Comment: Often I use "Advanced REST client" as a Chrome extension which let you define almost any headers you like. Try tampering with that a bit, I don't have any better idea for you unfortunately.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: I see the `Den Ärmel voller Asse,doch das Leben spielt` comment and the image profile element. Could you elaborate on what elements exactly you cannot find? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have some code like:

```
import requests as req
site = req.get('http://websta.me/n/victoria.a3456')
print(site.text)
```

You can change your headers of the request like so.

```
headers = {'':''}
site = req.get('http://websta.me/n/victoria.a3456', headers=headers)
```

The html file is a document which refers to other documents.  It's not a zip file.   Those other files (images, videos, etc..) are not embedded in the html document.  The web server is instructed to give you the html document and let the browser figure out how to download the linked documents from that html file.  The browser is doing more work in the background.  I would suggest looking at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to get the other elements of the site.

You can see that the images are in the site.text it's just a matter of putting in a 2nd request to download it.

```
import string
string.rfind(site.text, "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/10838359_831976973588137_408868997_n.jpg")
>>>10039
```